# Circle with coordinates and angles

Tags: qgis, polygon, circle

I have a csv file with points and convert them to polygons. I need to draw smt like [image]

The problem is that I have radius Bearing start and end poins
How I can to draw such circles in QGIS?
Can someone recommend?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].